# Continuous function between a lower semi-continuous function and an upper semi-continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, semicontinuous-functions

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $u: X \to [0, 1]$ an upper semi-continuous function and $l: X \to [0, 1]$ a lower semi-continuous function such that $u(x) < l(x)$ for each $x \in X$.

Does there exist a continuous function $f: X \to [0, 1]$ such that $u(x) < f(x) < l(x)$ for each $x \in X$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have found that one of the first versions of this statement can be found in Hans Hahn: Theorie der reellen Funktionen, p.164, 1921
The statement there does not even require the compactness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true. See the book

Engelking, Ryszard. "General topology."

On p.428 5.5.20 you find the following result as an exercise:

A $T_1$-space $X$ is normal and countably paracompact if and only if for each pair $f,g$ of real-valued functions on $X$, where $f$ is upper semicontinuous and $g$ is lower semicontinuous such that $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \in X$, there exists a continuous $h : X \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) < h(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$.

You will also find references to papers containing proofs, for example

Miroslav Katětov, On real-valued functions in topological spaces, Fundamenta Mathematicae 38 (1951), 85–91

as quoted in Dave L. Renfro's link.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See [Katětov–Tong insertion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kat%C4%9Btov%E2%80%93Tong_insertion_theorem). I suspect this result for your context (compact metric space domain) was proved earlier, but I off-hand I don't know. FYI, googling [semicontinuous + insertion + theorem](https://www.google.com/search?q=semicontinuous+insertion+theorem) will lead to many similar results. *(a few minutes later)* I just noticed you have strict inequality, whereas the theorem I cite involves non-strict inequality. I'm not sure whether your version can be obtained from what I gave, at least unless we assume (everywhere locally) a positive lower bound on the pointwise differences between the semicontinuous functions.

Comment: How would one deduce the strict version with the added hypothesis of $l(x) - u(x) > \varepsilon$ for each $x \in $X? Edit: Ok, I get it: consider the functions $u + \varepsilon/3$ and $l -\varepsilon/3$ and apply the theorem.

Comment: By a local positive bound on the pointwise differences I mean that for each point $x=a$ there exists $\delta > 0$ and $M > 0$ such that for each $x \in (a - \delta, \,a + \delta)$ we have $u(x) - l(x) \geq M.$ This allows you to locally get strict continuous insertion functions, which you can then appropriately "glue together" to get such a continuous function defined for all reals. (This is something I just came up with moments ago, so hopefully I'm not overlooking something obvious!)

Comment: This is actually what I realized I need so I accepted the answer.

Comment: Oops, in my earlier comment (which I can no longer revise), I should have written $l(x) - u(x) \geq M.$