# Finding a continuous function between upper and lower semi-continuous ones

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a separable metric space (but I suppose a paracompact space might be enough) and let $f , g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions such that:

- $f$ is upper semi-continuous,
- $g$ is lower semi-continuous,
- $0 \leq f(x) \leq g(x) \leq 1$ for every $x \in X$,
- $f(x)<1$ for every $x \in X$,
- $g(x)>0$ for every $x \in X$.

I'm trying to prove that there exists a continuous function $h : X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \leq h(x) \leq g(x)$ **and** $0<h(x)<1$ for every $x \in X$.

By the Michael selection theorem used for the set-valued mapping $x \mapsto \big\lbrace t \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \leq t \leq g(x) \big\rbrace$, we obtain a continuous function $h : X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \leq h(x) \leq g(x)$. However, this function $h$ might not satisfy the condition $0<h(x)<1$.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: See [Continuous function between a lower semi-continuous function and an upper semi-continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3307424/13130)

Comment: I've already checked that, but it does not seem to answer my question. My assumptions are weaker, namely I don't assume the strict inequality between the two functions (unless it's the extremal case when g(x)=1 or f(x)=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variant of the Michael theorem you've used:

> **Theorem (Michael):** The following properties of a $T_1$-space $X$ are equivalent:
>
> 1. $X$ is perfectly normal,
> 2. Every lower semi-continuous, set-valued mapping $X\to 2^\mathbb{R}$ with nonempty, convex values admits a continuous selection.

This is Theorem 3.1''' from E. Michael, "Continuous selections I", Ann. of Math. 63 (1956) 361–382.

Note that we don't require the set-valued mapping to have closed values (although this only works with $\mathbb{R}$ on the right side). Also we can drop both separable and paracompact assumptions on $X$, metrizable is enough. With that we can use a different set-valued mapping:

$$\varphi(x)=\begin{cases}
\big\{f(x)\big\} &\text{if }f(x)=g(x)\\
\big\{f(x)<t<g(x)\big\} &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The crucial observation is that $\varphi$ satisfies the above variant of the Michael theorem. The rest follows easily.